# How to loop a Menu after getting user input

Tags: java, loops

I am making a basic calculator.

I want it to ask the user for the left OPERAND, and then display a menu where the user has to pick the OPERATOR. After picking the operator it will ask for the RIGHT OPERAND. After doing this the MENU has to be looped until the user ENTERS "5" to exit, and then it will display the ANSWER.

How can I loop the menu after getting the RIGHT OPERAND?

I just started on this and this is what I have so far.

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

 public class program05 {


 public static void main(String [] args)
 {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


System.out.print("Enter the left operand: ");
String expression = "";
double lOperand = sc.nextDouble();
System.out.print("\n");


double resultsSoFar = lOperand;
expression += lOperand;
String user;
double rOperand;


do {System.out.println("\n" + "1 -> Multiplication" + "\n" + "2 ->    Division" + "\n" + "3 -> Addition" + "\n" + "4 -> Subtraction" + "\n" + "5 -> Exit" + "\n");
System.out.print("Choose an operator above: ");
user = sc.next();

System.out.print("Enter right operand: ");
rOperand = sc.nextDouble();

if (user.equals("1"))
{
    resultsSoFar *= rOperand;
}
else if (user.equals("5"))
{
    System.out.println("The answer is "+ resultsSoFar);
    System.exit(1);
}

}

 while (!user.equals("5"));



}
}
```

Comment: Would a do-while loop help?  Also, if you can put some more context around if this is a console app or an app with UI, it would help visualize the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: I just started on it, but I am stuck on looping the menu. I added what I have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example:

```
     if (user.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
        resultsSofar *= rOperand;
    } else if (user.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
        //your code here
    } else if (user.equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
        //your code here}
    } //more else if here
    else if (user.equalsIgnoreCase("5")) {
        System.out.println("The answer is "+ resutlsSofar);
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

Since you use double for operand, when the rOperand = 0, the result will be infinity.

Comment: I see. I didn't know you could add if-else statement in the do-while loop. I have one small problem now though. When I run program, and I press 5 it asks for the right operand instead of ending right away. I edited the code above so you can see what I have.

Comment: just put the if-else clause before the rOperand input.

Comment: Then the rOperand variable won't have a value.

Comment: so put it out of do-while loop for once

Answer (score 0):

just put the right operand in do-while loop then.

Comment: Yes, but how do I add if statement to say ( if user choses 1, then resultsSoFar *= rOperand). I don't know how to do that second part of the program when the user choses 1-5.  I need some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

hmm in this case, i sugesst you using switch - case, or even if-else clause in do-while loop.
for example:

```
  switch(user){
     case "1":
             resultsSofar *= rOperand;
            break;
    case "2":
            break;
    case "3":
            break;
    case "4":
            break;
     case "5": //Exit and print the answer
            System.out.println("The answer is "+ resultsSofar);
            System.exit(1);
 }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you mind showing me how an if-else clause looks like in a do-while loop? I was thinking of that, but since im new to programming I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: i do not recommend if-else clause. but if you want, i could show you.

Comment: Please do, I would like to see it if its not a problem.